# How do you install filemagic (libmagic) in Heroku?

Tags: ruby, heroku, rubygems

Usually it is brew install libmagic

I need it because the Ruby Gem ruby-filemagic' needs it.

Answer (score -6):

Try     `brew install magic`

If you don't have libmagic.1.dylib file in your system, you need
 to install it using port command

```
   sudo port install file
```